# Panel on Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, panel, dock

I am technologically challenged - truly - but I try to sort things out for myself because thats how one learns. Even a senior such as I. My problem is that I wanted to re-arrange the icons at the bottom bar panel and somehow the clock and other dock stuff ended up on the left. No matter what I try, I cant get those items back to the right side, where they used to be. I go into edit mode and I can actually move the clock to the right but as soon as I let the mouse button go, it flicks back to the left. So does the other icons. Please can anyone suggest what to do?

Answer (score 0):

No idea how to solve your problem directly, but maybe easiest way to add a New Panel (through the desktop menu) and start over there adding Widgets in the right place.
I also have many problems with Kubuntu. If you don't take it vanilla, it's not as easy as some people suggest. Good luck!